# Arabic appears in question marks when move data from Visual Studio project to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, arabic, collation

I have a problem with my Visual Studio/SQL Server project.

When I input data in VS project to be stored in the SQL Server database, the data I entered in Arabic appears as question marks in database.

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ADD_PRODUCT]
    @ID_CAT int,
    @ID_PRODUCT varchar(30),
    @Label varchar(30),
    @Qte int,
    @Price varchar(50),
    @Img Image
AS
    INSERT INTO [PRODUCTS] ([ID_PROD], [LABEL_PROD], [QTE_IN_STOCK],
                            [PRICE_PROD], [IMG_PROD], [ID_CAT])
    VALUES (@ID_PRODUCT, @Label, @Qte, 
            @Price, @Img, @ID_CAT)
```

The part in question is `@Label`.

This is the code in Visual Studio:

```
prd.ADD_PRODUCT(Convert.ToInt32(cmbCat.SelectedValue), txtDes.Text, txtRef.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtQnt.Text), txtPrx.Text, ByteImage);
```

The corresponding parameter is `txtDes.Text`.

I tried the collation method in SSMS but it doesn't seem to work when the data enters from another program (ie. Visual Studio).

I changed the data type from `varchar` to `nvarchar`, but with no avail.

Comment: You're using a `varchar` not an `nvarchar`. The procedure's parameters are a `varchar`, and I would suggest you check the definition of your table too. You need to use an `nvarchar` the whole way through.

Comment: That's exactly what was wrong, I changed vchar to nvchar everywhere except my stored procedure! Thank you

Comment: It's `varchar` and `nvarchar`, not "vchar" and "nvchar".